# how to connect to sqlserver database from java restful service in eclipse

Tags: java, web-services, rest

Is it possible to connect sqlserver database from restful service in java from eclipes.Most of the examples over internet suggest me of using mysql.Which is the best one to use?
Thanks in advance

Comment: both of them are good, and can be used as per your requirements

Comment: thank you.But can you help me with some reference to connecting to sql server. from webservice with eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a look on these links.

http://www.codingpedia.org/ama/restful-web-services-example-in-java-with-jersey-spring-and-mybatis/

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqldatasources.html

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html